# One of the @Test code block doesn't execute

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

[The TocheckApproval() code block doesnot get executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YsYO.png)
Can someone please suggest why this is happening and what steps do i need to take to execute both the @Test blocks

Comment: please add the code in the question instead of image reference. also share the testng results summary.

Comment: @Naveen, This was the error that i received WebDriverException : unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (277, 271). Other element would receive the click: <div class="modal-backdrop fade in" style="height: 974px;"></div>

Comment: Is the error trace different from the question asked here? The error suggests that you are clicking on a parent element instead of child or similar. so, when finding the element be more specific with the locators.

Comment: If i removed the TocheckRequestDecline code block, then the previous one (i.e) TocheckApproval got executed properly. Its only when i try to run both the tests together, is when it was not executing...not sure what the issue was there.

Comment: @Naveen...Btw, just tried running the code by using dependsOnMethods and both the tests got executed properly

Comment: that is what you want right? run both the methods? If you don't use `dependsOn`, the issue is observed in my case also (only one test getting executed), though not consistently reproduced. try with the latest version of testng.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether method order is guaranteed by TestNG framework.

If you want the method order like run the test only after some tests ran (and marked as PASS), you can use `dependsOnMethods` or `dependsOnGroups`

Eg:

```
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.asserts.Assertion;

public class TestExample {

    @BeforeTest
    public void beforetest(){
        System.out.println("before test ");
    }

    @Test
    public void Tocheckapproval() {
        System.out.println("in the method: Tocheckapproval");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"Tocheckapproval"})
    public void TocheckRequestDecline() {
        System.out.println("in the method: TocheckRequestDecline");
    }


    @AfterTest
    public void aftertest() {
        System.out.println("after test");

    }

}
```

---

If you want to define the method order of your choice and the tests should not depend on other tests, then instead of `dependecyOn*` (methods, groups), you can use `method Interceptors`.

`method Interceptors` provides the list of test methods that are going to run as one of the argument, then you can re-arrange as per your needs.

References:

1. http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors
2. http://beust.com/weblog/2008/03/29/test-method-priorities-in-testng/

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set any test priorities, that's why!
This is very easy to do, just stick the priority next to your @Test tag.

```
@Test (priority=1)
public void ToTestApproval(){
//do some stuff
}

@Test (priority=2)
public void ToCheckRequestDecline(){
//do some more stuff
}
```

As Naveen, mentioned above you can further refine the desired behaviour by using dependsOnMethods and dependsOnGroups.

PS. If this does not work, then it could be down to the @Test tag itself. Please double check that you are using TestNG annotation instead of Junit!

Best of luck!

Comment: I tried with the dependson method and it worked perfectly fine..will check by setting the priority as well..thanks for the suggestion